# Typecasting structures with different definitions

Tags: c, sockets, struct, posix, tcp

I came across this in socket programming:

```
struct sockaddr {
    sa_family_t sa_family;
    char        sa_data[14];
}

struct sockaddr_in {
    sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
    in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
    struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
};
```

These are the two structures with different type and  this is how I was made to use them

Client Side:

```
connect(sfd,(struct sockaddr *)&caddr,clen; //type casted one
```

Server Side:

```
bind(sfd,(struct sockaddr *)&saddr,slen);
accept(sfd,(struct sockaddr *)&caddr,&clen);
```

Here structures with different definitions are being type casted how does this affects the variable?

Even though I typecast I can access the variables like this:

```
printf("File Descriptor : %d\n", fd);
char *p = inet_ntoa(caddr.sin_addr);
unsigned short port_no = ntohs(caddr.sin_port);

printf("Ip address : %s\n", p);
printf("Ephimeral port : %d\n", port_no);
```

What is the use of this kind of typecasting? Even though I have have typecasted it how can I access those members of other structures (addr_in here)?
I want to know how these operations take place and understand the need for typecasting different structures.

Comment: It's commonly referred to as "type punning". It has many uses, from testing for system endiannes to OO programming.

Comment: If the sockets APIs were being invented now, they would not be implemented with the interfaces they currently have.  The `struct sockaddr` pointer nonsense is a relic of the days before the C standard (it was one step better than using `char *` — given that `void *` did not exist yet so `char *` was the nearest equivalent to a 'universal pointer').

Comment: It invokes undefined behaviour according to the C standard. as @JonathanLeffler pointed out it is a legacy we have to live with. Best is not to ask, not to wonder **and never to write such code yourself**.

Comment: @Olaf by using them I designed a server which can serve many clients and did not face any undefined behaviour ...
What kind of undefined behavior you are talking about ?

Comment: @Anjaneyulu Please read your last sentence carefully again. You ask me to _define_ **undefined** behaviour. Then read what that phrase implies.

Comment: @Olaf: it is not UB in ANSI C. And having `struct sockaddr` be an union of all the other socket address structures makes its use valid in all ISO C standards; in other words, the structure descriptions above are only valid for ANSI C, and need to be modified to work in ANSI C AKA C89,C99 and C11. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40558688/1475978) below.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: ANSI C is not C standard since 17 years now (I'm not in the mood to verify it is not UB in ANSI-C/ISO-C90 which I still think it is). Without a specific version we safely can assume standard C, i.e. C11 resp. C99 (which has much the same effective type rules). Short: yes it is UB! Re. the rest: We have to work with what OP posted, not what we might wish. And that is not a `union`, but two different `struct`s.

Comment: @Olaf: Yet, our C compilers don't just "follow the C standard"; their behaviour is defined with respect to the versions of the ISO C standard, as well as others like POSIX.1 which also has quite a few versions. Honestly, I don't understand your point at all, unless you mean *"nothing except the latest version of ISO/IEC 9899 matters"*, which is too fanatical and reality-denying to be worth even considering.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: I don't see any reference in the C standard to POSIX. As most implementations are not POSIX compliant, that would actually be quite a problem. The question does not mention POSIX explicitly, btw. If you'd read the forword of the 2011 version, you'd noticed that it **explicitly** states the second edition (aka C99) is **withdrawn**. Which means it is **not** standard anymore. If you read on, you will see the 1999 version had something similar for the first edition (C90, identical to  ANSI-C aka C89). Read my first comment carefully and stop this nonsense discussion.

Comment: @Olaf: You look only at the standard. I look at the tools, the compilers and the libraries, *the implementation*. Their documentation refers to various versions of the standards, including ISO C and POSIX, and others -- depending on the implementation, of course. That makes even withdrawn versions of standards -- but still referred to by the tool documentation -- valid, and useful. The difference between us is that I look at the tools, and what they claim to do; you look at a single document, and rely on that alone.

Comment: @Anjaneyulu: Please add the `posix` tag to your question. Socket facilities are not supported by standard C, and are currently standardized by POSIX.1, also known as [IEEE Std. 1003.1™](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). This would avoid the unfortunate bickering whether anything else than the current C standard matters with respect to this question.

Comment: @Anjaneyulu: I realized the bickering had derailed me from actually answering to *your questions*; instead, I had attempted to counter some claims here in the comments. To fix that, I rewrote my answer, focusing on the questions you stated, and practical examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perfect term will be "type punning" instead of calling it as typecasting.

sockaddr_in is for IP based communication in which we specify type of protocol, IP addr, port etc and sockaddr is a generic struct used in socket operation. The bind() uses sockaddr thus type punning is required.

You can search for type punning and can get more information.

Answer (score 10):

Note that socket operations are not standard C, but are standardized by [POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), also known as IEEE Std. 1003-1. Thus, the `posix` tag added by the OP is important to notice.

In particular, the IEEE Std. 1003-1 definitions for [`<sys/socket.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html) and [`socket()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html) require implementations to behave in a very specific way, regardless of whether the C standard declares such behaviour implementation defined or even undefined behaviour.

The POSIX.1 definition for [`getaddrinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html) has an example of a program that looks up an IPv4 or IPv6 socket address (`struct sockaddr_in` and `struct sockaddr_in6` types, respectively) for UDP. As explained in the [`<sys/socket.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html) definition, a `struct sockaddr_storage` type can be used for static storage, when the socket type is unknown.

Originally, `struct sockaddr` was used as an opaque type, to simplify the socket interface, while keeping minimal type checking. The form shown in the question are from ANSI C (ISO C89) era. Due to added pointer rules in later versions of the ISO C standard, the actual structures used by POSIX.1 implementations are slightly different; the `struct sockaddr` is actually a structure containing an union nowadays.

If the sockets API used a void pointer, `void *`, for the socket address structure, there would be no type checking. With a generic type, developers must cast their socket address structure pointer to `struct sockaddr *` to avoid a warning (or error, depending on compiler options used), which is hopefully enough to avoid the grossest mistakes -- like supplying e.g. a string instead, and wonder why it does not work, even though the compiler does not complain at all.

In general, this approach -- using a *"generic-ish"* type instead of a specific type -- is very useful in many situations in C. It allows you to create data-specific types, while keeping the interface simple, but retain at least some type checking. With well-designed structures, you can do things like generic binary tree structures for any kind of data, while only implementing one set of functions (compare to e.g. [`qsort()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) function in C). Because of this, I show later on how to define such structures/unions without invoking Undefined Behaviour in standard C.

> What is the use of this kind of typecasting?

A function that takes a pointer argument has two options. If the pointer argument is of type `void *`, the compiler will happily convert any object pointer to `void *` without warnings or complaints. If we want to only accept certain types of pointers, we need to specify exactly one type.

There are many types of socket addresses, and each socket address type has their own structure type. There is no way to tell the compiler to accept a pointer to one of maybe a dozen types of structures. Therefore, the pointer has to be cast, or *type-punned*, into the "generic" type, `struct sockaddr` in this instance.

Again, this approach does not lead to Undefined Behaviour in standard C in general, as long as the structures (the "generic" type in particular) are defined in a C standard compliant manner. It's just that the ones shown by OP are historical, not current, and cannot be really used as-is in current C due to strict aliasing requirements. I will explain later on how to do this.

In short, such type-punning is useful, when the function accepts pointers to certain types, and you wish to ensure only those types are supplied. In my opinion, the cast acts as a reminder for the developer to ensure they are using the correct type.

> How can I access members of the other types?

Well, you cannot.

Thing is, every socket address structure type has a common `sa_family_t` field, that is set to a value corresponding to the type of the socket address it defines. If you use a `sockaddr_in`, the value is `AF_INET`; if you use a `sockaddr_in6`, the value is `AF_INET6`; if `sockaddr_un`, the value is `AF_UNIX` (or `AF_LOCAL`, which evaluates to the same value as `AF_UNIX`), and so on.

You can only examine this common field, to determine the type. However, you can examine it through any type supported by the `struct sockaddr` type.

For example, if you have `struct sockaddr *foo`, you can use `((struct sockaddr_storage *)foo)->ss_family` (or even `((struct sockaddr_in *)foo)->sin_family`) to examine the type of the structure. If it is the type that contains the member you are interested in, *then* you can access it.

For example, to return the `uint32_t` corresponding to the IPv4 address in network byte order (most significant byte first), you can use

```
uint32_t ip_address_of(const struct sockaddr *addr, uint32_t none)
{
    /* NULL pointer is invalid. */
    if (!addr)
        return none;

    /* If IPv4 address, return the s_addr member of the sin_addr member. */
    if (((const struct sockaddr_storage *)addr)->ss_family == AF_INET)
        return ((const struct sockaddr_in *)addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;

    /* The pointer did not point to an IPv4 address structure. */
    return none;
}
```

The second parameter, `none`, is returned if a NULL pointer or a pointer to a non-IPv4 socket address structure was specified. Usually (but not in all use cases), a value corresponding to broadcast addresses (`0U` or `0xFFFFFFFFU`) can be used.

---

Historical background:

Using the structures shown in the question is not Undefined Behaviour in ANSI C -- the C standard of the era when they were widely used --, because 3.5.2.1 says

> A pointer to a structure object, suitably cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.  There may therefore be unnamed holes within a structure object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve the appropriate alignment.

and ANSI C has relaxed rules with respect to type punning than later C standards (C99 and C11), allowing back-and-forth casting between pointer types without issues. In particular, 3.3.4,

> It is guaranteed, however, that a pointer to an object of a given alignment may be converted to a pointer to an object of the same alignment or a less strict alignment and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

This means that there are no issues in ANSI C when casting a socket address structure pointer to or from a `struct sockaddr *`; no information is lost in the casting.

(It is not a problem that different socket address structures might have different alignment requirements. The initial member is safe to access in any case, because the pointer to the structure points to the initial member. It is mostly an issue for users who wish to support multiple different socket types using the same code; they must use e.g. an union, or allocate memory dynamically, for the socket address structures.)

---

In the current era, we need to define the structures (`struct sockaddr`, to be precise) a bit differently, to ensure compatibility with the C standard.

Note that this means the following approach is valid even on non-POSIX systems that support standard C.

First, there are no changes needed to the individual socket address structures. (This also means there are no issues with backwards compatibility.) For example, in the GNU C library, a `struct sockaddr_in` and `struct sockaddr_in6` are defined essentially as

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    sa_family_t     sin_family;    /* address family: AF_INET */
    in_port_t       sin_port;      /* port in network byte order */
    struct in_addr  sin_addr;      /* internet address */
};

struct sockaddr_in6 {
    sa_family_t     sin6_family;   /* address family: AF_INET6 */
    in_port_t       sin6_port;     /* port in network byte order */
    uint32_t        sin6_flowinfo; /* IPv6 flow information */
    struct in6_addr sin6_addr;     /* IPv6 address */
    uint32_t        sin6_scope_id; /* IPv6 scope-id */
};
```

The only important change needed is that `struct sockaddr` must contain a single union (preferably anonymous union for simplicity, but it requires C11 or at least anonymous union support from the C compiler used, and not many support the current C standard fully yet in 2016):

```
struct sockaddr {
    union {
        struct sockaddr_in   sa_in;
        struct sockaddr_in6  sa_in6;

        /* ... other sockaddr_ types ... */

    }  u;
};
```

The above lets the POSIX.1 socket interface work in standard C (from ANSI C or ISO C89 to C99 to C11 revisions).

You see, the ANSI C 3.3.2.3 says that *"If a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence, and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them"* with later standards adding *"anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible"*. The standards continue, *"Two structures share a common initial sequence if corresponding members have compatible types for a sequence of one or more initial members."*

Above, the `sin_family` and `sin6_family` members (of type `sa_family_t`) are such a common initial part, and may be inspected via any of the members in the `struct sockaddr`.

ANSI C 3.5.2.1 says that *"A pointer to a union object, suitably cast, points to each of its members, [..] and vice versa."* The later revisions of the C standard has the same (or similar enough) language.

This means that if you have an interface that can use a pointer to any of the `struct sockaddr_` types, you can use `struct sockaddr *` as a "generic pointer" instead. If you have, say `struct sockaddr *sa`, you could use `sa->u.sa_in.sin_family` or `sa->u.sa_in6.sin6_family` to access the common initial member (that specifies the type of the socket address in question). Because `struct sockaddr` is an union (or rather, because it is a structure with the union as its initial member), you can also use `((struct sockaddr_in *)sa)->sin_family` or `((struct sockaddr_in6 *)sa)->sin6_family` to access the family type. Because the family is the common initial member, you can do that using any type; just remember, that the other members are only accessible if the family matches the type the members belong to.

For current C, you can make the union anonymous (by dropping the `u` name near the end), in which case the above would be `sa->sa_in.sin_family` or `sa->sa_in6.sin_family`.

As to how this union-based `struct sockaddr` works on the other side, let's examine a possible implementation of [`bind()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html):

```
int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen)
{
    /* Clearly invalid sockfd? */
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        errno = EBADF;
        return -1;
    }

    /* Clearly invalid addr or addrlen? */
    if (addr == NULL || addrlen == 0) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    switch (addr->u.sin_family) {

    case AF_INET:
        if (addrlen != sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)) {
            errno = EINVAL;
            return -1;
        }
        return bind_inet(sockfd, (struct sockaddr_in *)addr);

    case AF_INET6:
        if (addrlen != sizeof (struct sockaddr_in6)) {
            errno = EINVAL;
            return -1;
        }
        return bind_inet6(sockfd, (struct sockaddr_in6 *)addr);

    default:
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The socket type dependent bind calls could be written equivalently as

```
        return bind_inet(sockfd, &(addr->u.sa_in));
```

and

```
        return bind_inet6(sockfd, &(addr->u.sa_in6));
```

i.e. taking the address of the union member, instead of just casting the pointer to the entire union.

---

When designing your own multi-subtype structures, there are four things to really remember, to stay standard C compliant:

1. Use an union type containing all of the subtypes as members as the "generic" type.
2. The union contains only one one subtype at a time; the one used to assign to it.
3. Optionally, add a subtype for accessing the type (and possibly the other members that are common to all subtypes) with an easy name, and use it consistently in the documentation.
4. Always examine the member that corresponds to the actual type first.

For example, if you are building an abstract binary tree of some sort -- perhaps a calculator? -- with different types of data stored at each node, you could use

```
/* Our "generic" type is 'node'. */
typedef  struct node  node;

typedef enum {
    DATA_NONE = 0,
    DATA_LONG,
    DATA_DOUBLE,
} node_data;

/* The minimal node type; no data payload. */
struct node_minimal {
    node      *left;
    node      *right;
    node_data  data;
};

struct node_long {
    node      *left;
    node      *right;
    node_data  data;   /* = DATA_LONG */
    long       value;
};

struct node_double {
    node      *left;
    node      *right;
    node_data  data;   /* = DATA_DOUBLE */
    double     value;
};

/* The generic type. */
struct node {
    union {
        struct node_minimal  of;
        struct node_long     long_data;
        struct node_double   double_data;
    } type;
};
```

To traverse such a tree, recursively, one could use e.g.

```
int node_traverse(const node *root,
                  int (*preorder)(const node *, void *),
                  int (*inorder)(const node *, void *),
                  int (*postorder)(const node *, void *),
                  void *custom)
{
    int retval;

    if (!root)
        return 0;

    if (preorder) {
        retval = preorder(root, custom);
        if (retval)
            return retval;
    }

    if (root->type.of.left) {
        retval = node_traverse(root->type.of.left, preorder, inorder, postorder, custom);
        if (retval)
            return retval;
    }

    if (inorder) {
        retval = inorder(root, custom);
        if (retval)
            return retval;
    }

    if (root->type.of.right) {
        retval = node_traverse(root->type.of.right, preorder, inorder, postorder, custom);
        if (retval)
            return retval;
    }

    if (postorder) {
        retval = postorder(root, custom);
        if (retval)
            return retval;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

where you supply the function called on each node in one (or more of) `preorder`, `inorder`, `postorder` parameters; `custom` being there only if you wish to provide the functions some context.

Note that with `node *root`:

- `root->type` refers to the union of all subtypes.
- `root->type.of` refers to the union member having type `struct node_minimal`; I named it so just to be playful. The intent is that you use this to access nodes of unknown type.
- `root->type.of.data` depends only on the type actually used for the node, one of the `DATA_` enums.
- `root->type.of.left` and `root->type.of.right` are also available regardless of the type of the node, and are used when you just traverse the tree and don't care about the exact types of nodes.
- `root->type.long_data` refers to the union member having type `struct node_long` (but you should only attempt to access it if `root->type.of.data == DATA_LONG`). Therefore, `root->type.long_data.value` is the `long value` member of a `struct node_long`.
- `root->type.double_data` refers to the union member having type `struct node_double` (but you should only attempt to access it if `root->type.of.data == DATA_DOUBLE`). Therefore, `root->type.double_data.value` is the `double value` member of a `struct node_long`.
- `root->type.of.data == root->type.long_data.data == root->type.double_data.data`, `root->type.of.left == root->type.long_data.left == root->type.double_data.left`, and `root->type.of.right == root->type.long_data.right == root->type.double_data.right`, because these are all common initial members, and it is explicitly allowed in C to access their value through any of the types in the union.

Note that the above traversal function is just an example; it uses a lot of stack for deep trees, and does not even try to detect loops. So, there is a lot of enhancements possible to make it a "library-worthy" function.

To print the value of a node, one could use for example

```
int node_print(const node *n, void *out)
{
    if (!out || !n) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    if (n->type.of.data == DATA_DOUBLE)
        return fprintf((FILE *)out, "%.16g", n->type.double_data.value);

    if (n->type.of.data == DATA_LONG)
        return fprintf((FILE *)out, "%lu", n->type.long_data.value);

    /* Unknown type, so ... return -1 with errno == 0, I guess? */
    errno = 0;
    return -1;
}
```

which is designed to work with the tree traversal function. You could print the values of tree `tree` in order (from left to right) to standard output using

```
node_traverse(tree, NULL, node_print, NULL, stdout);
```

Hopefully the above example shows you enough to give you ideas, but also enough to make you careful and think hard about the kind of interface you are designing.

If you think (many do) that I am incorrect in my reading of the C standard, please point out the section you believe contradicts the above. My point is not to be popular, but I do want to be corrected when I am wrong.

Note: Rewritten on 2016-17-11.

Comment: C **standard** is C11. NMot ANSI-C, not K&R-C. So, according to the standard, it **is** UB. The compiler can (and modrn compilers will) make assumptions about the types the code does not guarantee. I strongly doubt one can argue with a compiler to accept wishful thinking.

Comment: You said: _Because the structures share the same initial member …, their alignment is the same._. Counter example: `struct a1 { char c; double d; };` and `struct a2 { char c; char d; };` — the alignment requirements on these two structures are radically different (almost certainly requiring alignments of 8 and 1 respectively), despite them sharing 'the same initial member'.  This is an important defect in the answer; it is not completely debilitating to the answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Quite, good catch! I corrected that by noting how different socket address structures' alignment requirements affect a programmer. It does not affect the validity of my argument at all.

Comment: I'd wish that others downvoting this answer would *also* point out the defects they see, rather than just expressing their dislike quietly. I am not aiming for popularity here; my intent is only to show a (my own) reasoning why and how the structures OP showed were used in the past (during earlier versions of the C standards), and how they were adjusted and accommodated for in the C standards, as C and POSIX progressed. @Olaf: I would love to see your reasoning behind the UB claim, please. I respect you too much to see you drop this with a simple "trust me, I've got lots of reputation" quip.

Comment: Nominal, I agree that it would be nice if people always backed up their downvotes with comments, but you'll probably know from _Meta_ this has been discussed a lot, and it is always resolved that people may vote for any reason they like, they may do so anonymously, as long as they do not serial vote on one person. It's fine for posters to want to know who has downvoted or why, but related remarks probably belong in comments (if anywhere at all) since most people do not log in or vote. Thus, votes are not of interest to most readers.

Comment: @halfer: Thanks; no, I haven't looked at *Meta*, but I shall. I admit I'm just frustrated about how long-term members are not offering competing answers, but seem to prefer to try and quash the discussion altogether -- as if there is something wrong or distasteful in the question itself. I'm very disappointed in the members commenting negatively on the question; instead of offering anything useful or applicable, they are just trying to make it go away. This is social play, which severely detracts from having just the facts and opinions competing. Waste of time, really.

Comment: Well, if the output of the process is an answer as comprehensive as yours, then IMO it has not gone to waste - and you're getting upvotes too, so people and reading it and liking it. I don't post in the `c` tag, but I understand it can be a bit rambunctious!

Comment: @halfer: Sure, but you see, *I am not certain I am right*. This answer reflects my current understanding and best knowledge, *at this point in time*. I'd much rather see others post counter-arguments, so I can test my understanding against their arguments, and learn in the process. (It has taken four decades of practice, but nowadays I learn *fast*.) Stagnation, or offering simply unfounded claims, seems like such a waste of everyones effort and attention. Unless, of course, attention and gratification in the form of "votes" is the overall purpose.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: no, the purpose is not vote gratification (though the gamification system encourages community benefit by virtue of creating individual benefits). The point is that your votes indicate that people (a) read your material and (b) thought it was good or useful. That is why you should post. I am in favour of critiques in the comments, but it is worth remembering that Stack Overflow is not designed for discussions.

Comment: again and again perfect explanation sir. I today completed to read whole text(started yesterday). However, could you tell me meaning of "less strict alignment"(of a structure) or with an example??